# Read emails on specific date using google app script

Tags: date, google-apps-script, gmail

Hello guys I am working on a project where I want to read emails from gmail inbox on a specific date. I have referred the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app?hl=ja) but it hasn't been much helpful to me.

```
var master = SpreadsheetApp.openById(<SPREADSHEET_ID>);
var demosheet = master.getSheetByName("demo");
var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "dd/MM/YYYY");
var getdate = demosheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
//to get date from spreadshet
for(i=2;i<getdate.length;i++)
{
Logger.log(firstThread.getLastMessageDate(getdate[i][0]));  }}
```

Can anyone please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: At least point to the relevant section of the docs (mail services) and also show you tried to code something. Here people wont write the code for you.

Comment: Ohh! I didnt know that I have to post the code...here is what I have tried in the original question

Comment: and I have referred documentation of Gmail Services https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/?hl=ja and also the whole documentation  of classes GmailApp, GmailMessage and GmailThread, but I cant even get a clue how to read email on given date...

Comment: And I don't want anyone to write the code for me. Just point me in the right direction or the links that I can refer that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at GmailApp.search. Google for search format as its not in the docs. Probably uses syntax 'before:x after:y

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app?hl=ja#search(String,Integer,Integer)

Comment: Thanks that was helpful... I tried : before:2013/11/31 after:2012/3/1 from:xxxxxx and it worked.